# Vyatta order fails with vlan selection

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am implementing order Vyatta by selecting Vlans but It returns the following error.

```
Got 500 on https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder.json with body: {"error":"Subnets may not be specified for gateway orders.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"}
```

If the Vlan selection is set to be Auto assigned, the purchase process is working fine. Once I set the vlan selection then it returns error. I've already checked the selected Subnet Ids are correct. If you found any doubt, please let me know..

This is the ordering parameter I tried.

{"parameters":[{"complexType":"SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order","orderContainers":[{"complexType":"SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Hardware_Server_Gateway_Appliance","location":"352494","packageId":174,"quantity":1,"hardware":[{"complexType":"SoftLayer_Hardware","primaryBackendNetworkComponent":{"complexType":"SoftLayer_Network_Component","networkVlan":{"complexType":"SoftLayer_Network_Vlan","id":1149695,"primarySubnetId":610310}},"domain":"test.com","hostname":"ss"}],"useHourlyPricing":false,"primaryDiskPartitionId":1,"prices":[{"complexType":"SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price","id":74871},{"complexType":"SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price","id":21010},{"complexType":"SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price","id":342},{"complexType":"SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price","id":273},{"complexType":"SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price","id":55},{"complexType":"SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price","id":58},{"complexType":"SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price","id":876},{"complexType":"SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price","id":1267},{"complexType":"SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price","id":36044},{"complexType":"SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price","id":21},{"complexType":"SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price","id":17129},{"complexType":"SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price","id":57},{"complexType":"SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price","id":418},{"complexType":"SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price","id":906},{"complexType":"SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price","id":420}],"storageGroups":[]}]}]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you cannot specify subnets for gateways (even using the portal it does not work. That is the expected behavior), remove `"primarySubnetId": 610310` and it should work

Regards